# Undefined reference to WinMain with Netbeans and Cygwin 32 Bits

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin

yesterday I made a project in NetBeans 8.0.2 and Cygwin 32 Bits, today when I tryed to compile in a 64 Cygwin compiler, I got an error saying "Undefined reference to WinMain". What can I do to compile it in this 64 Cygwin compiler?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "Agenda.h"

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Agenda nueva;

    nueva.menuAgenda();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it might be that the problem is in Agenda.h, a missing close bracket or similar might cause such problem

Comment: I compile the same project at the 32 Bits machine and I there is no error

Comment: there is nothing wrong with this code, so the problem must be somewhere else

Comment: Looks like `nueva.menuAgenda()` must be called inside [WinMain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633559(v=vs.85).aspx). If `Agenda.h` uses `WinApi` for gui, then switch to Windows application. It uses `WinMain` instead ordinary `main` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix 32bit netbean with 64bit cygwin one

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=234221